# Override inherited variable name

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I would like to know if it's possible to override a variable's name (not value) when extending from it's super class.

Imagine this scenario:

```
public class Base {
   public  String A;
   public  String doSomething() { print(A) ; }
}

public class Sub1 extends Base {
   public String A1;
   public void setA1(String A1) { this.A1 = A1; }
}

public class Sub2 extends Base {
   public String A2;
}

Sub1 s = new Sub1();
s.setA1("1")
s.doSomething() // print "1"
```

I am curious if, somehow, I could make the variable A be the same as the variables A1 and A2 only to make code more readable in my sub classes.

Comment: it's not possible

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to achieve. You can just use the field `A` (BTW mind the naming conventions) in subclasses, you don't need to declare `A1` and `A2`.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to make my code more readable in the subclasses (It is only a matter of beauty, anything else)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can just "override" field `A` in `Base`. This way `Sub1` and `Sub2` classes will have they own `A` field name (but it will be different field with different (from `Base`) value).

```
public class Base {
   public  String A;
   public  String doSomething() { print(A) ; }
}
public class Sub1 extends Base {
   public String A;
   public void setA(String A) { this.A = A; }
}
public class Sub2 extends Base {
   public String A;
}

Sub1 s = new Sub1();
s.setA("1")
s.doSomething() // print "null", because original field has not been changed
```

Or you can just reuse `A` field in `Sub1` and `Sub2` classes:

```
public class Base {
   public  String A;
   public  String doSomething() { print(A) ; }
}
public class Sub1 extends Base {
   // removed: public String A1;
   public void setA(String A) { this.A = A; }
}
public class Sub2 extends Base {
   // removed: public String A2;
}

Sub1 s = new Sub1();
s.setA("1")
s.doSomething() // print "1"
```

Comment: You don't need to hide the field `a` with `private` modifier to make it "reusable". You can reuse `a` as field name in subclasses even if it is declared as public in the superclass.

Comment: This is not an "overriding" of a variable. It is a declaration of a new variable that has the same name as a variable in the super class. The simple answer to the question is that there is no "overriding" of variables in java.

Comment: @Dvorog, well, it's a question of what ubernal tried to archive in first place. The term is used incorrectly, of course, that's why it's in quotas.

Comment: I understand your point, but people with less knowledge might get confused and come to wrong conclusions by reading this answer. Maybe add a sentence at the beginning that says that there is no variable overriding in java. That is just my opinion tho :)

Comment: Okay. As I thought, what I am asking is not possible. It would have been something like (String A1 @overrides A) or something similar to say that my variable A now is named A1 in this sub class.